# Updating/inserting data

Tags: c#, sql-server

I created 3 tables

```
Clients: Client_ID, Client_Name, Client_Status,
Employees:Emp_ID, Emp_Name, Emp_Role  
EmpJobs:EmpJob_ID, Emp_ID, Client_ID, Hours_Spent, Job_Date
```

now I need a function where the user enters data (Hours_Spent, Job_Date) to EmpJobs based on Client_Name and Emp_Name. This is what I tried

```
string constring = "Data Source=baker-pc;Initial Catalog=BakodahDB;Integrated Security=True";
string sqlQuery = (@"INSERT INTO EmpJobs (Hours_Spent, Job_Date)
            values (@Hours_Spent,@Job_Date) 
            INNER JOIN Clients
            ON EmpJobs.Client_ID=Clients.Client_ID
            INNER JOIN Employees
            ON EmpJobs.Emp_ID=Employees.Emp_ID
            WHERE Clients.Client_Name=@Client_Name AND Employees.Emp_Name=@Emp_Name");

SqlConnection conDataBase = new SqlConnection(constring);
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conDataBase);
conDataBase.Open();
sqlCommand.CommandText = sqlQuery;
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Hours_Spent",SqlDbType.Int).Value = comboBox3.SelectedItem;
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Job_Date",SqlDbType.Date).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Text);
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Client_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox1.SelectedItem;
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Emp_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox2.SelectedItem;
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
conDataBase.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Saved!");
```

What am i doing wrong? what's the correct way to do it?

Comment: What difficulty are you facing with it?

Comment: There is no conditional insert, try UPDATE instead

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions? Is data just not populating? As @Am_I_Helpful said, what is the actual problem you are having?

Comment: SQL is way off.  Can you write a stored procedure for this assignment?  Going to be a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to insert new rows, then you want `INSERT . . . SELECT`.  It would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO EmpJobs (Emp_ID, Client_ID, Hours_Spent, Job_Date)
    SELECT e.Emp_ID, c.Client_ID, @Hours_Spent, @Job_Date 
    FROM Clients c JOIN
             Employees e
             ON c.Client_Name = @Client_Name AND e.Emp_Name = @Emp_Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a Select Query which returns you `Emp_ID` and `Client_ID` from the Name and then pass that query as the values for your insert query.

```
(@"INSERT INTO EmpJobs (Emp_ID, Client_ID, Hours_Spent, Job_Date)
            values 
            ((Select Emp_ID, Client_ID from Employees, Clients
            INNER JOIN Clients
            ON EmpJobs.Client_ID=Clients.Client_ID
            INNER JOIN Employees
            ON EmpJobs.Emp_ID=Employees.Emp_ID
            WHERE Clients.Client_Name=@Client_Name AND Employees.Emp_Name=@Emp_Name"),
            (@Hours_Spent,@Job_Date)));
```

Note: This query is just an example this probably might not work. But it is to give the idea or glimpse of the idea how it should work.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use insert/update with the conditions like this.
rather than this, create a stored procedure and pass 4 parameters to stored procedure.

In your stored proc, you can create the logic.

**note**: I am pointing you to the correct way of doing it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PRocname] (
@Client_Name nvarchar(your choice of length),
@Emp_Name nvarchar(your choice of length),
@HOurs_spent int,
@Job_date datetime)
AS

BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE  @ClientID INT ;
DECLARE  @EmpID INT ;
SET @ClientID = SELECT Client_ID from Clients where client_name =@Client_Name;
SET @EmpID = SELECT Emp_ID from Employees where Emp_Name =@Emp_Name;

INSERT INTO EMPJobs(Emp_ID, Client_ID, Hours_Spent, Job_Date)
VALUES (
@EmpID, @ClientID,@Hours_spent,@Job_Date

)



END
GO
```